# In the refrigerator was a bunch of bananas and some milk

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, grammaticality

it's grammatically wrong to say: "In the refrigerator was a bunch of bananas and some milk"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's incorrect.  It should be:

> In the refrigerator **were** a bunch of bananas and some milk.

The subject of the sentence is "a bunch of bananas and some milk," which is plural.  If the sentence is written correctly, it should be reversible:

> A bunch of bananas and some milk **were** in the refrigerator.

See the explanation under the heading "Reversed subjects and verbs" at:
http://www.wwnorton.com/college/english/write/we/ch6/21a.htm

Comment: While I have no argument with the answer, you will find instances where two items are regarded as complementary or a single dish and take the singular, as in: Peaches and cream was their favourite dessert. Oranges and Lemons is a game we played as children.

Comment: @Ronald Sole: If you reverse those sentences, you will see that they follow the rule I applied, which is also described in the link I posted.  In the sentence "Their favorite dessert was peaches and cream", the subject is "dessert", which is singular.  In the sentence "A game we played as children is Oranges and Lemons", the subject is "game", which is singular.  In the example lu castillo posted, on the other hand, the subject, "a bunch of bananas and some milk", is plural.

Comment: I also agree in principle, except that you are confusing the use of *subject*. To be in parallel, use *in the refrigerator* ***was*** *peaches and cream*. (Forget about the addition of *the dessert*.) That sentence is *still* correct, assuming that you're talking about a singular item. But if the peaches and the cream are not part of  a single dish, then it would be *in the refrigerator* ***were*** *peaches and cream*. The point is that the syntax *alone* in some cases can't determine the singularity or plurality of the subject.

Comment: @Jason Bassford: "Peaches and cream" is the subject in your sentence, and whether you use "is" or "are" depends on whether you consider "peaches and cream" to be singular or plural.  This is consistent with my explanation.  The bottom line is that the sentence is using a non-traditional word order, and the way to determine whether it's correct is to reverse it back to the traditional order and see if it's still correct.

Comment: @hguler Yes, that's exactly what I said. Except that you were saying the subject was *dessert*, which is not quite the same thing because that word is *unambiguously* singular.

Comment: @Jason Bassford: I do believe "dessert" is the subject in that sentence.  Please take a look at the examples given in the link I provided, under the heading "Reversed subjects and verbs".

Comment: @hguler But only because it's been specified. That's why it's *not* a good parallel to the actual question.  If the original question said "In the refrigerator was *a dessert of* ***a bunch of bananas and some milk***," there would be no question of singularity or plurality because *a dessert* would have been specified. By saying *a dessert of peaches and cream* you are cheating the question. You may be addressing reversing the sentence—but you are not addressing part of the problem: the *semantic* issue of singularity or plurality. It's assumed in this case, but the point is it's contextual.

Comment: @Jason Bassford: The question was whether a specific sentence is correct. It was not about whether "a and b" is singular or plural and whether this is always the case.  I'm not sure why you feel the need to keep insisting that I made an argument I never made.

Comment: @hguler My comments have been specifically in relation to the first two comments under this question.  But also, while reversing the sentence *may* make things clearer that is certainly not always the case. In some situations, regardless of *how* you structure the sentence, the ambiguity can remain.